# '0' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, mobile, beta

I just switched from jquery mobile alpha 2 to jquery mobile beta 1.0. I am using CDN access for the jquery javascript files and the css. I am getting some data from the server and displaying it in the list format. I am building list dynamically in the javasript file.

I was using

```
$('#detail').html(html);

$('#detail ul').listview();
```

to refresh my list after building it.

It was working well with alpha version of jquery mobile but now without changing a single line of code I am trying to run it using jquery mobile beta  and it is breaking with the following error:

Webpage error details

> Message: '0' is null or not an object
>   Line: 133
>   Char: 183
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://user.mydomain.com/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js

Am I doing something wrong or some issue with beta version of css file?

EDIT:

I am getting the data in json format (say result object)using ajax call and displaying it like this:

```
var html = "<ul id="contactDetails" data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-inset="true">";

html += "<li data-icon='false'><Email:<a href=mailto:'"+  result.Data.email_address_1 + +"'>" + result.Data.email_address_1 + "</a></li>";
```

html += 'ul close tag'

```
$('div#page2 div#contentMain div#details ul#customerDetails').html(html)
$('div#page2 div#contentMain div#details ul').listview();
```

Althought I can see the data coming and displaying properly BUT without the style.

Hope this helps to understand the problem.

Raman

Comment: I suggest you use the unminified version and have a look at the line where the error is thrown.

Comment: your information is not going to help at all. Identify the piece of code that makes `0` null or not an object. It means your using on the jQuery methods wrongly somewhere. A stacktrace would really help.

Comment: @Raynos, I have edited the question. See if that can help.

Comment: @itizme, there are syntax errors when you create the `html` variable.. You are missing the `+` between the hardcoded string and the variables.. and you are missing a variable as well at the `<a href=mailto:'" + +"'>`

Comment: oh sorry, the html code has been stripped out.

Comment: And the `var html` line has bad quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this with Jquery Mobile forum and the following solution works for me.

```
     $('#details').html(html)
     $('#page2').page();
     $('ul#customerDetails').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your examples you are doing

```
$('div#page2 div#contentMain div#details ul#customerDetails').html(html)
$('div#page2 div#contentMain div#details ul').listview();
```

But `id`s are unique so there is no reason to use multiple id to define the hierarchy..

Just use

```
$('#customerDetails').html(html);
$('#details ul').listview();
```

Also make sure you fix your string concatenations .. and that `result.Data` contains what you think it does..